# "including" vs. "including on"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have issue with the usage of "including on" in the following sentence:

*The EU and its court have opened procedures against Poland's current government, saying its changes to the justice system and opposition to some EU decisions, **including on** relocation of migrants, have gone against the 27-member bloc's principles.*

Should I treat "including on" as a synonym for "including"?

Please, share your thoughts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an elided **decisions** in between. "Including on" is not a set phrase. If you read _**including [decisions] on**_, the matter is clarified.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.